# Order by in SP with input param

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, order-by

I have a table with 2 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
id int, 
name nvarchar(50)
)
go 

insert INTO Test(id, name)
VALUES (1, 'aa')
insert INTO Test(id, name)
VALUES (2, 'bb')
insert INTO Test(id, name)
VALUES (3, 'aa')
```

I need a stored procedure that selects data from my table in different orders.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE testSelect(
@OrderColumnID int
)    
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM test
    ORDER BY CASE @OrderColumnID WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 2 THEN 2 END ASC
END
```

`WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 2 THEN 2` means, that if input param = 1, the table must be ordered by the 'id' column, if input param = 2 table must be ordered by the 'name' column.

When I execute the SP like:

```
EXEC dbo.testSelect @OrderColumnID = 2
```

I get an incorrect result.

I don't want to rewrite my SP to use dynamic SQL, or separate it into if ..... else if .... blocks like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testSelect(
@OrderColumnID int
)    
AS 
BEGIN
    IF @OrderColumnID = 1
    SELECT *
    FROM test
    ORDER BY 1
    ELSE IF @OrderColumnID = 2 
    SELECT *
    FROM test
    ORDER BY 2
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query means, if @OrderColumnID = 1 then order by 1 (as int, not as first column). So you get random order.

You can get expected result by:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testSelect(
    @OrderColumnID int
)
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY CASE @OrderColumnID WHEN 1 THEN Id END ASC,
    CASE @OrderColumnID WHEN 2 THEN name END ASC
END
```

Read more about it here ["Specifying a conditional order"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx). The `ORDER BY CASE...` construction may be able to use indexes to avoid a sort if you add an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on SQL Server 2008 SP1 CU5 or later.

Of course, you can use dynamic SQL. Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testSelect(
    @OrderColumnID int
)
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @OrderColumnID INT = 2,
    @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY '+CAST(@OrderColumnID AS VARCHAR(2))

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
```

I think that it is easiest way and I don't know why you don't want to do that (with appropriate protection from SQL injection attacks).